# GeoNetwork map viewer not displaying title name in Thai language?

Tags: geoserver, geonetwork, internationalization

I am using **GeoNetwork 2.10.3** to **Add WMS** server from **GeoServer** and am unable to display its title using the **Thai** language.

I have tested an edit string with the Thai language and it worked.

It is only the map viewer which cannot display it.

Can you help me to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can testing WMS server at URL http://nsdiportal.gistda.or.th/geoserver/wms